# Number of elements in array greater than given number

Tags: algorithm, sorting, binary-search

Okay , so I know this has been asked countless times because I googled in every form possible but could not get an answer.

I have an array say A= {10, 9, 6, 11, 22 }. I have to find number of elements greater than 11.

I know this can be done using Modified Binary Search but I need to do it in O(1) time. Is this possible?

(Keeping in mind we are taking the elements as input, so may be some pre-computation can be done while taking the input. )

Comment: Will the question always be how many elements are greater than 11?  Or, does your solution have to be flexible to answer how many elements are greater than any number?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have multiple queries, so I can be asked the number of elements that are greater than any arbitrary number like 11 ,21,30...etc.

Comment: I don't think this can be answered in constant time, for any arbitrary number.  Best you could do (I think) would be to maintain a binary tree of some sort.  Then you could answer the question in `O(lgN)` time.  But this still isn't constant.  I hope someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen May be if this helps- I am not asking for the whole process to be O(1) , but only the retrieval part , so if you sort the array in O(logn) that is not counted in O(1).

Comment: Is number range limited by reasonable value?

Comment: @MBo Numbers can be upto 10^9 . I think I get what you are thinking , making an array upto the maximum element for eg array B , and B[i] will indicate number of elements greater than i. But the problem here is i can go upto 10^9 so such array is not possible . Are you thinking the same thing?

Comment: @AyushGoyal: The array size can be max(A)-min(A)+1, not 10^9.

Comment: What is the maximum number of elements in the array? How much memory are you allowed to use?

Comment: @LiorKogan if A={0,5,6,10^9} , that's where the problem lies

Comment: @user3386109 max elements in array are 10^5

Comment: Binning might be an answer, depending on how much memory you're allowed to use.

Comment: SInce you mention pre-computtation, does this means you have the input array and all querys at the beginning?

Comment: Btw you don't need to construct a binary tree to get O(log n), sorting the array is enough and then use interval halving to find the smallest index bigger than the given number. The result will be that index. No balancing issues (it is only O(log n) on balanced binary tree, otherwise O(n)) etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove all the 0s from the array and count them. Now you know the result for input 0: n - count. Afterwards subtract 1 from all the remaining elements in the array. The goal of this step is to bring the numbers in the range of [0,999999999]. If the input is greater than 0 subtract one from it too otherwise return result immediately.
2. Sort the numbers and think of them as 9 digit strings (fill up with leading 0s).
3. Build the tree. Each node represents a digit. Each leaf has to store the amount of numbers greater than itself. I don't think the number of nodes will be too high. For the maximum n = 10^5 we can get about 5*10^5 nodes (10^5 different prefixes brings us down to about level 5 after that we have to have linked lists to the leaves 10^5 existing + 4*10^5 for the linked lists).
4. Now you have to go through all non-leaf nodes and for all the missing digits in the children create direct links to the next smaller leaf. About an additional 9*4*10^5 nodes if you represent the links as leaves with the same count as the next lower leaf.
5. I think now you can theoretically get O(1), because the complexity of the request doesn't depend on n and you will have to save much less than when creating a hash map. For the worst case you have to go down 9 nodes, this is a constant that is independent from n.

Comment: Step 4 could be skipped and you still get O(1) in step 5. The worst case is going down to level 8, finding all the leaves are bigger, going up to root (or node with good child is found) and down again, so 8 + 8 + 9 steps but a lot less to save. While the going up could be skipped by saving the best so far when going down, so 8 + 9 = 17 steps.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider first sorting the input and then inserting it in a Y-fast trie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie), where each element will also point to its index in the sorted input, and thus the number of elements greater and lower than it. Y-fast tries support successor and predecessor lookup in `O(log log M)` time using `O(n)` space, where `M` is the range.

Answer (score 0):

This answer makes the assumption that building the data structure itself does not have to be constant time, but only the retrieval part.

You can iterate through your array of numbers and build a binary tree.  Each node in this tree will contain, in addition to the numerical value, two more points of data.  These points will be the number of elements which each node is both greater than and less than.  The insertion logic would be tricky, because this state would need to be maintained.

During insertion, while updating the counters for each node, we can also maintain a hashmap indexed by value.  The keys would be the numbers in your array, and the value could be a wrapper containing the number of elements which this number is greater and less than.  Since hashmaps have `O(1)` lookup time, this would satisfy your requirement.

If you need `O(1)` lookup time, only a hashmap comes to mind as an option.  Note that traversing a binary tree, even if balanced, would still be a `lg(N)` operation in general.  This is potentially quite fast, but still not constant.

Comment: Actually the lookup is being performed in a loop , so only the lookup needs to be of constant time . What do you think would be the time comp of building the said tree?

Comment: The worst case time to build an entire binary tree is `O(N^2)`, but this assumes building the entire tree at once.  Inserting a single new node would be worst case `O(N)` (a tree which looks really like a list), but it could be faster.  But in any case, if you want constant lookup time, I think you need a map here.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to decrease time complexity beyond this is to increase the space complexity.

If you have a range of elements of the array limited, lets say [-R1, R2], then you can build a hashmap over this range, pointing to linked list. You can precompute this hashMap, and then return results in o(1).